# Как мне пронумеровать массив в discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord

Как мне пронумеровать массив, я пробовал сделать это через `for`, но у меня не получилось.

Пример того, чего хочу получить:

1. server1
2. server2
3. server3
4. server4
5. server5

Но я получаю: e r v e r

Мой код:

```js
let list = client.guilds.cache.array().sort().join(`\n`);

for(let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  message.channel.send(list[i])
}
```

Comment: В `list` там строка, судя по всему, а `list[i]` - это ее символ. Что написали, то и получили. К слову, строчка `client.guilds.cache...` абсолютно бесполезна для потенциальных отвечающих. Не думали? Что попадает в переменную? Надо захардкодить в вопросе какое-нибудь конкретное значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let data = client.guilds.cache.array()
 for(let i = 1; i < client.guilds.cache.size; i++) {
  message.channel.send(i + data[i].name)
}
```

Советую ещё почитать про циклы https://learn.javascript.ru/while-for